# Listen for http request in the body of RequestHandler

Tags: python, tornado

There is a strange API I need to work with. 
I want to make a HTTP call to the API and the API will return success but I need to wait for request from this API before I respond to the client.

What is the best way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

Is it an option to make your API REST-ful?
An example flow: Have the client POST to a url to create a new resource and GET/HEAD for the state of that resource, that way you don't need to block your client while you do any blocking stuff.

Comment: The client is not in my control and blocking it is a requirement